# HDMI audio "unplugged" when I came back to desktop

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi, xrandr

Ubuntu recognizes my HDMI audio is unplugged.

If I run command below, then it recognizes "plugged":

```bsh
    xrandr --output HDMI-2 --auto --set "audio" off

    xrandr --output HDMI-2 --auto --set "audio" on
```

Why?

Is there another solution to fix it?

---

~$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.18.0-16-generic (buildd@lcy01-amd64-022) (gcc version 8.2.0 (Ubuntu 8.2.0-7ubuntu1)) #17-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 8 00:06:57 UTC 2019

---

$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=cosmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.10"

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Comment: OMG your xrandr command fixed a very bad case of "no sound after wake up" that I've been having for months! Now I have a way to restore sound w/o rebooting, THANK YOU!!